# How does the ME3: Datapad app calculate readiness?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-datapad

When you complete a mission in the ME3: Datapad app, how does it calculate your new total?  Is the percentage award added to the old total for a new overall readiness percentage?

For example, if I have 60% readiness in a sector, and I complete a mission that gives 1.3% readiness, will my new readiness rating in that sector be 61.3%?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, when you complete a mission in a sector, the new readiness percentage is the previous readiness percentage plus the readiness value for that mission.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm trying to calculate approximately how long it should take me to obtain 100% readiness in each sector using only the Datapad app.  Minus any readiness decay, that is.  I haven't yet plotted the rate of decay into my formula.  Or the several minutes it seems to take to complete any action with this slow, slow app.

Comment: Do you have all of the upgrades? That can affect the calculations.

Comment: Indeed I do.  Except for the Galactic Command Coordination.  That's just useless.  According to my calculations, if a player stays on top of things and keeps his fleets deployed even *most* of the time, he'll reach 100% readiness way before he reaches 500,000.

Comment: There's always getting back to 100% for a second playthrough (like I will probably do eventually)

Comment: That's a fair point. In that case, it would be worth it to keep going for the Galactic Command Coordination bonuses.  Even despite the apps flaws.

Comment: @RESPAWN they just Nerfed the cost of the upgrades...I just bought all three for 100,000

Comment: @Tyroni it looks like it's actually only 75,000 for the three advanced upgrades

Comment: I'm glad I saw this now with only 150,000 credits banked.  If I waited till I had 500k and saw that the price of the first upgrade was dropped to 10K, I would be slightly perturbed.